# Posture for listening to Kiddush and Havdalah

Tags: halacha, kiddush, havdalah, standing-sitting, chazon-ish

I heard that when anyone else is listening to someone make *kiddush* or *havdalah*, *l’chatchilah* they must be either sitting or standing depending on what the person making *kiddush* or *havdalah* is doing. In addition, the *Chazon Ish* indicates that if a person did not do so he/ she is not *yotzei* even *b’di’eved*. Can you please tell me the source for this?

Comment: The source for what? For the Chazon Ish?

Comment: sitting or standing for havdalah and kiddush.

Comment: The source for being in the same position as the _mevareich_?

Comment: @user6633 No source, offhand, but I think that you would follow the custom of the host, just as derech eretz, unless he is doing something wrong, or he doesn't mind your doing otherwise. E.g. - in some homes I attend, the family washes BEFORE Kiddush, and I follow the host's custom. How would Kiddush / Havdalah follow different rules than this?

Comment: What is the halachic source for this? (i.e. kitzur shulchan aruch, mishna berurah etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SA OC 396:6

> אומר הבדלה מיושב: הגה: ויש אומרים מעומד (אגודה וכל בו ואגור) וכן
>   נוהגיןבמדינות אלו:

MB 27

> מיושב - מיירי כשמוציא לאחרים ידי חובתן וע"כ כיון דאחד פוטר חבירו יש
>   להם לכולם לעשות קביעות ובמעומד לא הוי קביעות והי"א ס"ל דכיון שהוא
>   הלוית המלך אין מלוין אלא מעומד ולענין הקביעות סגי כשמזמנין הכל ועומדין
>   ומכוונין כדי לצאת וס"ל דמתוך שקובעין עצמן כדי לצאת ידי ברכת הבדלה מהני
>   נמי קביעות זו לצאת בברכת היין [ב"י]:י

Comment: I assume that these halachot apply only to Kiddush & Havdalah at home. Or, do they apply in shul, also? I thin in both cases everyone should stand b/c of kavod hatzibbur?

Comment: I wouldn't think the shul changes it. Though, it is an interesting point. Maybe the fact they are in shul makes them concentrate more? Personally, i stand according to my minhag, and i ask any guests to stand as well.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme It is OC:296:6 and not 396:6. I am unable to make an edit to correct the answer as edits need to be at least six characters long.

Comment: Siman 296, not 396

Answer (score 0):

The source from the Hamotze Bracha is in the Beit Yosef ,Orach Haim [קסז][י-יא].he also brings some source from the Gemara [ברכות מב ב-מג ג] .The idea is that you show that you are a group and you all are  *yotzei* in one Bracha,by all sitting/standing together.But,from there it is easy to conclude that if the *mevareich* explicitly has *chavana* for you,you are *yotzei*,standing or sitting.

(I dont have enouth rep' to comeent this + I dont have any books here.can someone check and edit?)

also in Mishna Brura [רעא מו],we can see something aout this ,that the sitting(that his Psak) is for *kviut* and not only a part of the Kidush.